# Insert SMS programmatically on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, sms

I have the following code which works fine in older versions of Android, but not on 4.4.2. No errors occur and nothing in logcat, but the messages do not show up in the default SMS app in the emulator. So my question is why it doesn't work on 4.4.2 and what I have to do to make it work again.

```
private void addSMS()
{       
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    cv2.put("address", "+91956322222");
    cv2.put("date", "1309632433677");
    cv2.put("read", 1);
    cv2.put("type", 2);
    cv2.put("body", "Hey");
    getContentResolver().insert(uri, cv2);
    /** This is very important line to solve the problem */
    getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/-1"), null, null);
    cv2.clear();
  }
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Do you get an exception or other indication of failure? What happens? Anything in the log file?

Comment: Thanks, but no. Nothing shows up in logcat, no errors are thrown, the code is executed just fine, but no messages show up in the default SMS app on the emulator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting from Android 4.4 Kitkat, it is not possible to perform any kind of SMS related operations without being the default SMS app. Restore and Backup apps cannot do it either. Most of them have updated their app to support this functionality and now ask the user to select them as the default SMS app.

Comment: Found all the necessary details here btw: http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Answer (score 0):

Android KitKat update stopped supporting **writing the SMS** with other apps. You can only listen but cannot write. If you want to send sms, you have to send it to default SMS intent and the user **has to approve and click SEND** before sending SMS.

For your ref : [SMS Provider Update](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-sms-provider)

Comment: Thanks. However, I do not want to send sms, rather just populate the sms database on the device. I know of several apps that do backup and restore of SMS, so it must be possible somehow, right?